# Is term 神経の鈍い (insensitive) common?

Tags: terminology

Is term 神経{しんけい}の鈍{にぶ}い commonly used to describe a direct person?

Comment: 「[無神経]{むしんけい}な人」のほうがよく使うかも。。「[鈍感]{どんかん}な人」ともいうかな・・・

Comment: "a direct person" in your question seems very subltle to answer. If you show me some example like **here** as for the person, it will help me to answer your question whether the term 神経の鈍い is proper or not. https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100709183545AAjIqM7

Comment: No, it is not used to describe a *direct person* at all. What gave you this idea? Was it mentioned in some dictionary? If so, which?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky JMDict is the only online dictionary for people who do not speak Japanese. 神経の鈍い: http://tangorin.com/general/%E7%A5%9E%E7%B5%8C%E3%81%AE%E9%88%8D%E3%81%84. Direct is a synonym to "insensitive", at least in U.S. work environment.

Comment: for other readers, on insensitive/direct equivalence: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/389310/216883

Comment: Игорь, спасибо за разъяснение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is term 神経の鈍い (insensitive) common?

For "insensitive (person)", I think 「[無神経]{むしんけい}な（人）」「[鈍感]{どんかん}な（人）」 are quite common. 「神経の(orが)鈍い（人）」 or just 「鈍い（人）」 would also be fine. (Some people may use 「デリカシーの(orが)ない（人）」 but this might sound a bit old-fashioned.)

> Is term 神経の鈍い commonly used to describe a direct person?

I don't think so. For "direct (person)", I think 「[率直]{そっちょく}な（人）」 or 「はっきりした（人）」 would be more common.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean "honest person" by "direct person"? If so, no. 神経の鈍い means "dull" or "slow." and it has only negative nuances.

Answer (score 2):

"insensitive" may be not the best translation here.

Taken literally, the expression means "(someone) with dull/blunt nerves", i.e. someone who does not get nervous/excited easily or is not affected by outside annoyances.

"thick-skinned" may be a better one. If you do pick "insensitive", it would be in the sense "unfeeling". I doubt "direct" works at all here.

if you do need a good term for "direct", I'd suggest you to make a new question, explaining what exact meaning of "direct" you need and what options you found.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for the meaning of "direst person" [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100709183545AAjIqM7), where it is written directly as:

I am a very direct person. Tell it like it is, honest, straight to the point. I dont mean it in a harmful way and appreciate when others are the same with me...

Now I'm thinking about the possible answers as: 空気｛くうき｝の読｛よ｝めない人、無神経｛むしんけい｝な人、忖度｛そんたく｝しない人｛ひと｝...。

By the way, 忖度｛そんたく｝ *sontaku* or 忖度｛そんたく｝する *sontaku-suru* was a buzz word in Japan several months ago.

I don't think a direct person would 忖度｛そんたく｝する *sontaku-suru*, and he would not like to 空気｛くうき｝を読｛よ｝む *kuuki-wo-yomu*.

According to the article [here](http://www.huffingtonpost.jp/2017/03/23/moritomo-sontaku-in-english_n_15572790.html) the meaning of 忖度 *sontaku* is very difficult to tanslate into English. In this article there are several minute and careful translations.

If you allow me to translate *sontaku-suru* into English, I would say *to stand in the situation of the partner and snuggle up to the feeling of him/her*. So, I said a *direct person* would not like to *sontaku-suru*.

Comment: I'm afraid your last paragraph is quite hard to make sense of. Also, the question was not about 忖度 so the whole last half is kind of strange.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I'm thinking about the possible answers for a direct person are like: 空気｛くうき｝の読｛よ｝めない人｛ひと｝, 無神経｛むしんけい｝な人, or 忖度｛そんたく｝しない人. Among of the three terms, I thought only 忖度 is very difficult to translate, so I showed an article written about 忖度.　Thank you!